# Debug React Native from remote node server

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, react-native, expo

I'm using [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/debugging) to build a mobile app using React Native.

I'm also trying to do the development on a Pixelbook, so my node server is running on a remote Linux machine.

The Expo app is working just fine, and I've been able to get Redux Dev Tools working, but how about React Dev Tools with a setup like this?

It seems like the remote dev tools presume the node server is running on the same machine with Chrome installed. When I try to launch remote JS debug from the developer menu, here's what my node server spits out

```
07:43:37: Launching Dev Tools...
07:43:37: Google Chrome exited with error: { Error: spawn chromium ENOENT
07:43:37:     at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
07:43:37:     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
07:43:37:     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
07:43:37:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
07:43:37:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
07:43:37:   code: 'ENOENT',
07:43:37:   errno: 'ENOENT',
07:43:37:   syscall: 'spawn chromium',
07:43:37:   path: 'chromium',
07:43:37:   spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui' ] }
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Sadly, I can't remember, it's been a while since I was working on this app. IIRC, I don't think I figured this out...

Comment: hi, just figured it out yesterday. I put my RN server on a Docker container and in this case you should have the RN Debugger open beforehand. if you are running the server locally then it open automatically. but not when on Docker... no idea why. :)

Comment: Ok neat. I will try this next time I am working on an RN app!